# If else and case in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I tried to write a ALU component.

```
wire[4:0] OP = Instruction[8:4];
wire[3:0] temp = Instruction[8:5];
always_comb begin
  if( temp == 4'b1000)  begin
    Halt   = 0;
    branch_en = 1;
    lookup_en = 0;
    reg_wr_en = 0;
    ALU_src =   0;
    MEM_WRITE = 0;
    Acc_wrt  =  0;
    Mem_Acc =   0;
    Acc_src =   2'b00;
  end 
  else if(temp == 4'b1111) begin
    Halt   = 0;
    branch_en = 1;
    lookup_en = 0;
    reg_wr_en = 0;
    ALU_src =   0;
    MEM_WRITE = 0;
    Acc_wrt  =  0;
    Mem_Acc =   0;
    Acc_src =   2'b00;
  end
  else begin
    case(OP)
      0:  begin
        Halt   = 0;
        branch_en = 0;
        lookup_en = 0;
        reg_wr_en = 1;
        ALU_src =   0;
        MEM_WRITE = 0;
        Acc_wrt  = 0;
        Mem_Acc =   0;
        Acc_src =   2'b00;       
      end
      1:  begin

        Halt   = 0;
        branch_en = 0;
        lookup_en = 0;
        reg_wr_en = 0;
        ALU_src =   0;
        MEM_WRITE = 0;
        Acc_wrt  =  1;
        Mem_Acc =   0;
        Acc_src =   2'b00;       
      end
      ....
      15:  begin
        // Halt inst
        Halt   = 1;
        branch_en = 0;
        lookup_en = 0;
        reg_wr_en = 0;
        ALU_src =   0;
        MEM_WRITE = 0;
        Acc_wrt  =  0;
        Mem_Acc =   0;
        Acc_src =   2'b01;       
      end
    endcase 
  end
 end
```

So basically first I want to check if the instruction[8]
I got error `Error (10166): SystemVerilog RTL Coding error at Ctrl.sv(23): always_comb construct does not infer purely combinational logic.`
Ctrl.sv(23) is`if( temp == 4'b1000)  begin` first if statement.
How can I do if else in a always_comb ?

Answer (score 3):

You are generating latches which are not a combinatorial circuit.

To avoid that you have to make sure that every variable is assigned a value in every possible path. There are two ways to do that:

1. Have a final 'else' for every 'if' (you have that, so that is good) and have a default for every case (you have not done that!).
2. Assign a default value to every variable at the start.